# How to apply conditional values on select with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use the ***case when*** function when creating views from joined tables?

```
t1.daycol     |    t2.daycol    |    t1.v    |    t2.v   |   r
2020-06-30    |  2020-03-30     |    3       |    1      |   2      <<<< r = t1.v - t2.v for t1.daycol and t2.daycol are in the same year
2020-03-30    |  2019-12-30     |    1       |    6      |   1      <<<< r = t1.v for t1.daycol and t2.daycol are not in the same year
```

I tried to add another column then subtract it later with

```
create view offperiod as
select t1.*, t2.*, 
case when year(t1.daycol) > year(t2.daycol) then 0 else t2.daycol,
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on timestampdiff(day,t2.daycol,t1.daycol) > 0 and timestampdiff(day,t2.daycol,t1.daycol) < 85
```

But I got some syntax error in this statement.

Is it possible to do that in the line when creating views?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: You need to add an `end` keyword, so change `then 0 else t2.daycol,` to `then 0 else t2.daycol end,`

Comment: It only says "select is not valid at this position" @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Dai Yea that seemed to be the case. Added the ```end``` it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
case when t1.daycol.year > t2.daycol.year then 0 else t2.daycol,
```

in many ways.

Perhaps you intend:

```
(case when year(t1.daycol) > year(t2.daycol) then 0 else t2.daycol end) as something
```

Note that the comma is removed, `year()` is used as a function, and the `case` expression has an `end`.

You probably can't select `*` from both tables -- if columns have the same name, that will cause a problem for the view.